# Using symfony normalizers for translation, good or not?

Tags: symfony, serialization, normalize, symfony6

I am using symfony normalizer for translations. Every time I have specific object I want to translate data in that object. Is it correct to translate data in normalizer?

```
class ExampleNormalizer implements NormalizerInterface, CacheableSupportsMethodInterface
{
    public function __construct(private ObjectNormalizer $normalizer, private readonly TranslatorInterface $translator)
    {
    }

    public function normalize($object, string $format = null, array $context = []): array
    {
        $data = $this->normalizer->normalize($object, $format, $context);
        $data['name'] = $this->translator->trans(sprintf('adaptation.name.%s', $data['name']), [], 'example');
        return $data;
    }

    public function supportsNormalization($data, string $format = null, array $context = []): bool
    {
        return $data instanceof Example;
    }

    public function hasCacheableSupportsMethod(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't do that. I would implement the TranslatorInterface. The interface does not matter where you get your translation from. Thus, the translation component is available as intended.

https://github.com/symfony/contracts/blob/main/Translation/TranslatorInterface.php

Comment: I am using TranslatorInterface but within normalizer. I added example code in question

Comment: With your example I understand what you mean. That's how I would have done it and it's exactly right.